# SQLite with android, how do you connect to online db?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

My godaddy hosting supports SQLite the code below doesn't give me any errors but it doesn't work because it still needs to connect to a remote linux server. The usual way I do this is by using my terminal in OS X and type in:

$ ssh USERNAME@192.168.1.1

and from there I can create a database and start querying it. How do I do this in Eclipse IDE?

```
//callback to be invoked when "button" is clicked
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {

                   //ALERT: string message
                   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ALL FOR THE EMPIRE!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    //SQLite query
                SQLiteDatabase db;
                db = openOrCreateDatabase("testSQL",SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY,null);       
                db.execSQL("create table answerSheet3 (attendant text, view varchar, row varchar, seat varchar, submittime date time default current_timestamp, answer char)");
                    //SQLite query


               }
             });
```

Comment: I'm not confortable with godaddy, but I would strongly recommend to write an API to access your SQLlite db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sqlite doesn't require any special database server or anything it's a lightweight one and  It's just a direct filesystem engine that uses SQL syntax.So you write API for connecting the SQLite DB using HTTP.For creating API you can use eclipse IDE.